# Google Cloud Platform: Connect domain to VM with SSL enabled to run shiny app

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

I'm struggling. Today I'm struggling with Google Cloud Platform (GCP) and Shiny:

- I managed to get my Shiny-App created with R-Studio on GCP to run on Shiny-Server on GCP
- I can access the shiny-app through a static external IP that I have created in GCP > VPC Network >  External IP addresses by accessing http(s)://myexternalip:3838/name_of_my_shiny_app/

So far so good.

Now I want to route my (sub-)domain to this App with SSL enabled

What I did:
- Created custom domains via GCP > App Engine > Settings > Custom domains and added the domain (with TXT google site verification)
- I followed the App Engine tutorial and created the "hello world"-App. The "hello world"-App is accessible via my domain. So that is pretty awesome.

What I cant figure out (for the life of me):
- I have custom domain pointing to my hello world App
- I have Shiny-App running on VM
-> How to I route incoming traffic from the domain to the Shiny-App?

I have been clicking wildly on things like VPC Routing, Load balancing and cloud DNS, googled a lot and am no wiser than before, maybe even less.

I am thinking that if I could put the Shiny App into a docker and hook it up as a App Engine App that I might succeed, but that seems like a bad workaround for a quite simple problem...

I have also read [Google Cloud Platform - Compute Engine/App Engine - SSL/HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883359/google-cloud-platform-compute-engine-app-engine-ssl-https) and think that this might be the right path. But quite frankly I have a hard time understanding the answers... Also a load-balancer seems like something that one would use if one had any real load... I'm hesitating to introduce an additional layer of complexity at this point...

As you might notice, I am struggling here and have hardly an idea what I am doing. So please be fair and talk *slowly* ;)

And as always thanks a bunch in advance, guys!

Chris

Comment: Do you just want a subdomain to point to a compute engine instance?

Answer (score 0):

There is a particular documentation in Google Cloud to Secure Custom Domains with SSL without the need to create and configure a Load-Balancer in front.

It state: "HTTPS connections on your custom domain will be enabled automatically using managed SSL certificates. Once your custom domain is mapped to your application and you have configured your DNS records, App Engine provisions a managed SSL certificate". More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl).